# Create folders in custom installation profile fails when usind drush site-install

Tags: 8, drush, files, installation-profiles

I am working on a custom installation profile, and am using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as part of creating custom folders inside `<drupal-root>/sites/sitename.tld/`.
It works as expected when using the UI installation process, but when I try to run it through `drush site-install my_custom_install` it fails. I expect this is because $_SERVER is never set in the CLI (at least that is what I could understand from search around for a solution).

In terms of the error I get when it fails, it is just a permission denied for creating the folder, since it tries to create it in `/sites/sitename.tld` in the root of the server, which it naturally does not have access to. It's this path that is correctly getting the document root in the UI, but not in CLI.

**Code example that is creating the folder**

```
copyTheme($from, $to, &$context) {
  $site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

  $context['message'] = 'Copy theme';

  $source = $site_root . $from;
  $destination = $site_root . $to;

  try {
    // If the destination directory does not exist create it
    if (!is_dir($destination)) {
      if (!mkdir($destination, 0777, TRUE)) {
        // If the destination directory could not be created stop processing
        throw new Error('Could not create custom theme folder \'' . $destination . '\'');
      }
    }

    //if (chmod($destination, 0777)) {
    //  rcopy($source, $destination, $context);
    //}
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    \Drupal::logger('custom_installer')->error($e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

**Snippet of the actual error output during `drush site-install`**
In the error, `installtester.dev` is the `$project_domain` and `installtester` is the `$project_name`.

```
Error: Could not create custom theme folder '/sites/installtester.dev/themes/custom/installtester' in /var/www/drupalvm/drupal/webroot/profiles/contrib/custom_installer/batch.inc on line 20 #0 /var/www/drupalvm/drupal/webroot/core/includes/batch.inc(252): copyTheme('/themes/contrib...','/sites/installt...', Array)
#1 /var/www/drupalvm/drupal/webroot/core/includes/form.inc(874): batch_process()
#2 /var/www/drupalvm/drupal/webroot/core/includes/install.core.inc(619): batch_process(Object(Drupal\Core\Url), Object(Drupal\Core\Url))
...
```

In case it is relevant, I am doing the development on drupal-vm via vagrant and virtualbox on a windows 10 machine.

**Question**
Is there a better way than using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the document root? one that will work both using UI install and `drush site-install`?.

Alternatively, is there a parameter I can check for if I use the `--root` option for `drush site-install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works.

Drupal sets it's own constants, such as `DRUPAL_ROOT` which can be used instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

So, all I had to do was to change `$site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to `$site_root = DRUPAL_ROOT;`, for it to work correctly when installed via Drush.